# document.domain bug

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

```
Permission denied for <http://www.guy.lt> (document.domain=<http://www.guy.lt>) to get property Window.document from <http://www.guy.lt> (document.domain has not been set).
```

If this is not a bug, then how to explain such behavior? (or at least the error message) And, of course, how to fix it?

The other strange thing is that in:

```
debug.log('0');
document.domain = 'guy.lt';
debug.log('1');
document.domain = 'wwww.guy.lt';
debug.log('2');
```

`debug.log('2')` is never triggered. However, there is no error in the `console`. Script just stops executing.

Comment: @minitech: editing the question and then answering it, does not answer the original question. The error message is as displayed.

Comment: what is the actual domain of the page that runs this script?

Comment: I wouldn't be so brash as to assume that just because you don't understand the same-domain security model that it automatically means it's a bug.

You really need to list the FULL domain names of both sites. Not just what you are setting document.domain to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't infer what you are doing wrong based on your question, but to enable cross-domain scripting, you have to set `document.domain` to the same common part of the domain. Also relevant:

- If one side uses the `foo.guy.lt` and the other side uses `bar.guy.lt` then you have to set `document.domain = "guy.ly"` on both sides.
- If you set `document.domain` to `guy.lt` then the actual domain has to be `guy.lt` itself or a subdomain of `guy.lt`. You can't make (sub)domain names up.
- You always have to explicitly specify the value of `document.domain`, even if the value is the actual domain itself.
- You can never change `document.domain` back to a more specific subdomain. So if the actual domain is `www.guy.lt`, than you can change `document.domain` to `guy.lt`. However, after this change you can't change it back to `www.guy.lt`.

Examples:

```
// Actual domain is "www.foo.com"
document.domain = "foo.com"; // this is valid

// Actual domain is "bar.foo.com"
document.domain = "www.foo.com"; // this is invalid, "bar.foo.com" is not a subdomain of "www.foo.com"

// Actual domain is "blah.bar.foo.com"
document.domain = "bar.foo.com" // Ok
document.domain = "foo.com" // Still ok
document.domain = "bar.foo.com" // Invalid, you can't change it back to a more specific domain.
```

Comment: Yes, but in my case both sides use `document.domain` `www.guy.lt`. Therefore, this comment is irrelevant.

Comment: What Elian said is completely relevant.

Comment: To be fair, I updated my answer based to Guys reply and the updated question :-)

Comment: It still doesn't answer my question, since the error is about trying to connect from www.foo.com to www.foo.com where document.domain on both is set to the same www.foo.com. This might be FF bug or something because I didn't get the same error in Chrome. Anyway, setting document.domain to foo.com on both ends fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Cross domain access via `document.domain` is only allowed if *both* pages explicitly set `document.domain` to the same value.  This is a necessary security measure; otherwise `something.company.com` could set `document.domain` to `company.com` and read things from `company.com`.  As it is, it can only do that if `company.com` explicitly opts in by setting `document.domain` to `company.com`.